# Momentum and collisions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, work

> Two blocks of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ connected by a spring of force constant $k$.The block $m_1$ is suddenly given a velocity $v_1$. Find the work done by the spring on both the blocks when it has reached its maximum compression?

Comment: Is the system in an open universe? In which direction the velocity is given? also where are your workings?

Comment: I really can't make sense how a certain velocity $v_1$ is given only to $m_1$ without disturbing the other parts of the system.

Comment: @Timaeus: If you are providing force, you are bound to move the second mass also unless the spring has some considerable mass.

Comment: @Timaeus: Okay considering your fact, I'll post an answer, check that.

Comment: @Timaeus: I really forgot that OP hasn't shown any working or so. However thanks for the fact:)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: ...I wonder who upvotes things like this? Or really, more importantly, why?

Answer (score 0):

Initially both the masses were at rest; let $m_1$ be at left & $m_2$ be at right.

Relying on the argument presented by @Timaeus, when $m_1$ got the velocity, it moves faster than $m_2$ as it has zero velocity. As time goes on, the length of the spring will decrease as $x_2\lt x_1$ where $x_i$ is the displacement of mass $m_i$ . The spring gets compressed by $x_2 - x_1$ . The spring will provide restoring force which will accelerate $m_2$ but decelerate $m_1$ as long as both the masses have same velocity which would be $V$, say. Maximum compression occurs then. Considering law of conservation of momentum, we get $$m_1v_1 = (m_1+m_2) V.$$

Initial KE is $\dfrac{1}{2} m_1v_1^2$. Final KE is $\dfrac{1}{2} (m_1 + m_2)V^2$.

The loss in the kinetic energy is the work done by the spring. $$\therefore W_\text{spring} =\dfrac{1}{2} (m_1 + m_2)V^2 -\dfrac{1}{2} m_1v_1^2 \\ \implies W_\text{spring}=\dfrac{1}{2} (m_1 + m_2)\left(\frac{m_1 v_1}{m_1 + m_2}\right)^2 - \dfrac{1}{2} m_1v_1^2.$$

Comment: Notice that if you continue the algebra, the work reduces to -1/2$\mu v_1^2$, where $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the system.  It's interesting to see how often a reduced mass term shows up in two-mass systems.

Comment: @Bill N: Yes, you are right, sir. BTW, I didn't complete the work because it would be against the policy of this site to completely provide answer to a homework-question which shows no effort at all. Even I dared to post the answer as it did make me ponder a bit as you can see my argument with Timaeus; otherwise I never ever answer a homework query that doesn't show any effort:)